# Cannot set Opacity property on ScatterViewItem after an animation has been performed

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, properties

I am currently removing an element from the user interface by fading it out. This works as expected.

```
public void HideShape()
{
    if (this.TangibleShape != null)
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.From = 1.0;
        animation.To = 0.0;
        animation.AutoReverse = false;
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);

        Storyboard s = new Storyboard();
        s.Children.Add(animation);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this.TangibleShape.Shape);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(ScatterViewItem.OpacityProperty));

        s.Begin(this.TangibleShape.Shape);
        s.Completed += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // call UIElementManager to finally hide the element
            UIElementManager.GetInstance().Hide(this.TangibleShape);
       };
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to set the opacity to 1 again in some cases but the `TangibleShape.Shape` (it's a `ScatterViewItem`) ignores the command. If I fade out again, the element becomes visible and immediately starts fading out. I don't know how to fix this problem. Does anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: This is because the Animations Timeline is still holding the DependancyProperty, you have to reset the DependancyProperty, you can use `TangibleShape.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.OpacityProperty, null);` to reset the OpacityProperty on `TangibleShape`

Comment: it's cos of Binding Precedence. In the `s.completed` lambda add `this.TangibleShape.Opacity = 0.0; this.TangibleShape.BeginAnimation(ScatterViewItem.OpacityProperty, null);` and you should be sorted to later then apply Opacity = 1 when required.

Comment: I did add the code in the `s.Completed` handler as recommended, but I still can't set the opacity property to any value ... is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d33ca82-2c02-4004-8b37-47edf4cca34e/scatterviewitem-and-

ScatterViewItems are a bit special in this case :)

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, you should post it as an answer. After a day you can mark it as the accepted answer and you'll get a shiny new badge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void HideShape()
{
    if (this.TangibleShape != null)
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.From = 1.0;
        animation.To = 0.0;
        animation.AutoReverse = false;
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
        animation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop; // needed

        Storyboard s = new Storyboard();
        s.Children.Add(animation);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this.TangibleShape.Shape);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(ScatterViewItem.OpacityProperty));

        s.Completed += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // call UIElementManager to finally hide the element
            UIElementManager.GetInstance().Hide(this.TangibleShape);
            this.TangibleShape.Shape.Opacity = 0.0; // otherwise Opacity will be reset to 1
        };
        s.Begin(this.TangibleShape.Shape); // moved to the end
    }
}
```

Answer found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d33ca82-2c02-4004-8b37-47edf4cca34e/scatterviewitem-and-